# Everything freezes except mouse. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity, gnome

I use ubuntu 12.10 32bit
Gnome 3.6.0 with Unity
GPU: Intel 3000 HD

In about this computer:
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
GPU      : Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

Everything fine, except occasionally everything freezes (display, keyboard, mouse clicking actions) except the movement of the mouse (and I can observe it's movement).
Before this problem occur I was having troubles with false X serv alerts.

I'm just asking if noone come up with solution, at least someone with my type of machine and my configurations (given up above) to run 
    $uname -r
and tell me the Kernel version. (Of course if he doesn't have these kind of problems)

Comment: I have this issue in Core i7, HD3000; i'm using 3.8.0-19-generic

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me when I was using KDE on Debian sid. So I stopped using it and switched to LXDE. It might happen due to shortage of CPU as in my case I was on a really old PC.